# How to reset stylesheet file over apllication while the app is running?

Tags: qt, qt5

main.cpp

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
QApplication app(argc, argv);

QFile data("://stylesheet.qss");  // this is a stylesheet file in images.qrc file
    QString style;
    if (data.open(QFile::ReadOnly))
    {
        QTextStream styleIn(&data);
        style = styleIn.readAll();
        data.close();
        app.setStyleSheet(style);  // I want this line to restart with different style-sheet file 
    }
app.setWindowIcon(QIcon("://images/BEL.jpg"));

MainWindow w;
w.setFixedSize(500,350);
w.showMaximized();
return app.exec();}
```

theme.cpp

```
theme::theme(QWidget *parent) :
QDialog(parent),
ui(new Ui::theme) {    
ui->setupUi(this);
ui->apply_button->setDefault(1);
QButtonGroup *radio=new QButtonGroup;
radio->setExclusive(true);
radio->addButton(ui->radio_blue,2);
radio->addButton(ui->radio_grey,3);
connect(radio,SIGNAL(buttonClicked(int)),this,SLOT(function(int)));}
theme::~theme()
{
delete ui;
 }
 void theme::on_pushButton_2_clicked()
{
this->close();
 }
  void theme::function(int value)
  {   if(value==2){
    qDebug()<<"blue";}
  else if(value==3){
    qDebug()<<"green";}
 else
    qDebug()<< "error";
  }
```

I have main.cpp and theme.cpp and many other files. I have two radio-buttons in my theme window. I have two style-sheet files for both gray and blue color. When I check any button it should apply all over application as shown in main.cpp.

The problem is when I start application it applies file just once. But I want to make it run when I check other button. Is there anyway so that I can now in main.cpp that particular button is pressed and application can be restarted applying style sheet file for that button?

Comment: What is your exact problem? You can't read file? You can't apply stylesheet?

Comment: I got solution of my problem

Comment: So, provide an answer or remove your question

Answer (score 1):

```
  theme::theme(QWidget *parent) :
   QDialog(parent),
   ui(new Ui::theme)
   {
  ui->setupUi(this);
  switch(radio)
{
case 1:
    ui->radio_blue->setChecked(1);
    break;
case 2:
    ui->radio_red->setChecked(1);
    break;
case 3:
    ui->radio_green->setChecked(1);
}
QButtonGroup *radio=new QButtonGroup;
radio->setExclusive(true);
radio->addButton(ui->radio_blue,2);
radio->addButton(ui->radio_red,3);
radio->addButton(ui->radio_green,4);
connect(radio,SIGNAL(buttonClicked(int)),this,SLOT(function(int)));
qApp->installEventFilter(this);

}
theme::~theme()
 {
delete ui;
 }

 void theme:: function(int value)
  {
if(value==2)
{
    qDebug()<<"blue";
    theme_val=2;

}
else if(value==3)
{
    qDebug()<<"red";
    theme_val=3;


}
else if(value==4)
{
    qDebug()<< "green";
    theme_val=4;

}
else
    qDebug()<< "error";

  }
    void theme::on_apply_button_clicked()
  {
if(theme_val==2)
{
    qDebug()<< "blue";
    QFile data1("://stylesheet.qss");
    QString style1;
    if (data1.open(QFile::ReadOnly))
    {
        QTextStream styleIn(&data1);
        style1 = styleIn.readAll();
        data1.close();
        qApp->setStyleSheet(style1);
    }
    radio=1;
}
else if(theme_val==3)
{
    qDebug()<< "red";
    QFile data("://stylesheet1.qss");
    QString style;
    if (data.open(QFile::ReadOnly))
    {
        QTextStream styleIn(&data);
        style = styleIn.readAll();
        data.close();
        qApp->setStyleSheet(style);
    }
    radio=2;
}
else if(theme_val==4)
{
    qDebug()<< "green";
    QFile data2("://stylesheet2.qss");
    QString style2;
    if (data2.open(QFile::ReadOnly))
    {
        QTextStream styleIn(&data2);
        style2 = styleIn.readAll();
        data2.close();
        qApp->setStyleSheet(style2);
    }
    radio=3;
}
else
    qDebug()<< "errror" ;
close();
}
```